# create pdf/a compliant pdf with libharu

Tags: pdfa, libharu

i'm trying to create an pdf/a compliant document with libharu, but it doesnt work.

The created pdf isn't pdf/a compliant.

Here is my small example:

```
        pdf = HPDF_New(error_handler, NULL);
        if (!pdf) {
            printf("error: cannot create PdfDoc object\n");
            return;
        }

        HPDF_STATUS stat;
        HPDF_Date date;

        stat = HPDF_SetInfoAttr(pdf, HPDF_INFO_TITLE, "Rechnung");
        stat = HPDF_PDFA_SetPDFAConformance(pdf, HPDF_PDFAType::HPDF_PDFA_1A);
        HPDF_Page page = HPDF_AddPage(pdf);

        CString hpdfFontName = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(pdf, "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf", HPDF_TRUE);
        HPDF_Font title_font = HPDF_GetFont(pdf, hpdfFontName, "WinAnsiEncoding");

        HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize(page, title_font, 10);
        HPDF_Page_BeginText(page);

        HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos(page, 10, 190);
        HPDF_Page_ShowText(page, "Dies ist ein Test");
        HPDF_Page_EndText(page);


        HPDF_SaveToFile(pdf, "");
        HPDF_Free(pdf);
```

I'm validating the pdf doc with veraPDF and these are the errors i'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<report>
  <buildInformation>
    <releaseDetails id="core" version="1.14.105" buildDate="2019-10-24T22:54:00+02:00"></releaseDetails>
    <releaseDetails id="validation-model" version="1.14.105" buildDate="2019-10-24T22:59:00+02:00"></releaseDetails>
    <releaseDetails id="gui" version="1.14.8" buildDate="2019-10-24T23:11:00+02:00"></releaseDetails>
  </buildInformation>
  <jobs>
    <job>
      <item size="68127">
        <name>C:\test.pdf</name>
      </item>
      <validationReport profileName="PDF/A-1A validation profile" statement="PDF file is not compliant with Validation Profile requirements." isCompliant="false">
        <details passedRules="103" failedRules="4" passedChecks="426" failedChecks="4">
          <rule specification="ISO 19005-1:2005" clause="6.2.3" testNumber="4" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="1">
            <description>If an uncalibrated colour space is used in a file then that file shall contain a PDF/A-1 OutputIntent, as defined in 6.2.2</description>
            <object>PDDeviceGray</object>
            <test>gOutputCS != null</test>
            <check status="failed">
              <context>root/document[0]/pages[0](6 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](7 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[3]/fillCS[0]</context>
            </check>
          </rule>
          <rule specification="ISO 19005-1:2005" clause="6.8.2" testNumber="1" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="1">
            <description>The document catalog dictionary shall include a MarkInfo dictionary with a Marked entry in it, whose value shall be true.</description>
            <object>CosDocument</object>
            <test>Marked == true</test>
            <check status="failed">
              <context>root</context>
            </check>
          </rule>
          <rule specification="ISO 19005-1:2005" clause="6.8.3" testNumber="1" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="1">
            <description>The logical structure of the conforming file shall be described by a structure hierarchy rooted in the StructTreeRoot entry of the document catalog dictionary, as described in PDF Reference 9.6</description>
            <object>PDDocument</object>
            <test>StructTreeRoot_size == 1</test>
            <check status="failed">
              <context>root/document[0]</context>
            </check>
          </rule>
          <rule specification="ISO 19005-1:2005" clause="6.7.2" testNumber="1" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="1">
            <description>The document catalog dictionary of a conforming file shall contain the Metadata key.</description>
            <object>PDDocument</object>
            <test>metadata_size == 1</test>
            <check status="failed">
              <context>root/document[0]</context>
            </check>
          </rule>
        </details>
      </validationReport>
      <duration start="1587388142413" finish="1587388142429">00:00:00.016</duration>
    </job>
  </jobs>
  <batchSummary totalJobs="1" failedToParse="0" encrypted="0">
    <validationReports compliant="0" nonCompliant="1" failedJobs="0">1</validationReports>
    <featureReports failedJobs="0">0</featureReports>
    <repairReports failedJobs="0">0</repairReports>
    <duration start="1587388142413" finish="1587388142429">00:00:00.016</duration>
  </batchSummary>
</report>
```

So it is possible to create an pdf/a compliant document with libharu? 
Where is my failure?

Comment: I don't think HaruPDF, neither PoDoFo, have a format compliant approach. They are just technical bricks, you to know what is compliant and what is not.